# CSS highlighting break after text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to add breaks between text highlighting in CSS (where it doesn't highlight in a box, but instead ends the highlighting after the end of the line)

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

My CSS for this block is

```
h2.slide-title{
background: #89ce40;
padding: 0 0 0 !important;
line-height: 1.3;
box-decoration-break: clone;
text-transform: uppercase;
opacity: 0.9;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
-o-box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.button-medium{
background: #89ce40;
line-height: 1.3;
box-decoration-break: clone;
text-transform: uppercase;
opacity: 0.9;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
-o-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

the HTML is:

```
<div class="slide-caption">
 <div class="slide-content">
    <h1><strong>COMPREHENSIVE IT SERVICES YOU CAN TRUST</strong></h1>
     </div>

    <h2 class="slide-title"> Let us help you develop an IT Optimization Strategy and Define your technological priorities </h2>

    <a class="slide-link button button-medium" href="http://18.205.33.160/index.php/itone-method/?customize_changeset_uuid=fde7f902-ae22-4db9-abef-fe976403cdb7&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0&amp;customize_autosaved=on" target="_self"> Learn how we can help you succeed </a>
```

When I add `display: inline;` it breaks it, for the top portion it removes the highlighting entirely and when I do it for the bottom portion the button moves up into the second paragraph of text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a background color to text, but with space blank space between lines of paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527765/add-a-background-color-to-text-but-with-space-blank-space-between-lines-of-para)

Comment: I viewed that and unfortunately the answer provided, did not provide me with what I needed... I edited the post explaining why on the last line. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use the `<mark>` tag and then just edit the background color of that. Or alternatively wrap your text in `<span>` and add background to that.